# 4-Pin programming interface

Tags: jtag, swd, cortex-m0

Could anybody give me a hint on how to wire a proprietary device, that uses a Nordic NRF51822 chip and only provides the following pins: {3.3V, GND, RST, CLK} to a programmer. I am pretty sure it is using SWD, but I don't know where to attach the DIO pin to.

Comment: Edit and add datasheet to your question.

Comment: Hi Bence, thanks for the fast reply, unfortunately I don't have a datasheet, but I know it is programmed using 4 pins and their names. As it is an nrf51, I assume it is programmed using SWD, but that might be wrong.

Comment: You can use an internet search engine to find the data sheet...

Comment: Without datasheet it will be quite hard to do anything with the chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nRF51822 for sure uses SWD. You can debug it with OCD + libSWD from CEDROM repo.

PIN23(SWDIO/nRST) <- reset is shared with Data pin.
PIN24 (SWDCLK)

You need to also attach GDN and VDD.
Look at the pinout in page 11 in below document.

Datasheet can be found [here](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF51822_PS_v3.1.pdf)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation and the hint how to debug. I tried reprogramming via an http://redbearlab.com/blenano/#mk20usbboard as it uses SWD and I thought it works on all cortex m0. Should it work with an  nrf51-dk then?

Comment: I do not know this board but if this have SDW it should work. I made quick look into web and they even mention nrf5122 so it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide the datasheet for your exact part it's difficult to proceed, but a quick google search for "NRF51 datasheet" gave me [this](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF51822_PS_v3.1.pdf).

It looks like RST is active low, and if it is not held low then it acts as the SWDIO pin (shown in Section 2.2.1 in the datasheet). I don't expect this will change much in different versions of the device.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @DerStrom8 that is absolutely correct and you helped me a lot. I must have overlooked that.